# Can you install external packages through the canopy gui?

Tags: enthought

Is it possible to install external packages from the canopy gui?

I can easily do this at the CLI, e.g.:
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/jkitchin/pycse/archive/master.zip

but I am going to be teaching a class of 50+ students this fall using canopy, and I would really like it if I could have them do this through canopy.

Any thoughts? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can do this through the ipython console by prefixing with a !:

!pip install --upgrade https://github.com/jkitchin/pycse/archive/master.zip

Thanks Robert Kern from Enthought for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

No, currently it is not possible to install external packages from the Canopy gui.